# Calculate the sum of an array by removing a string?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with 3 indices for each student:

```
var students = [
    ['Toto', 4, 17],
    ['Titi', 11, 12],
    ['Tata', 12, 14]
];
```

I have to calculate the sum for each student. Except that, I must avoid the string.

My result obtained for the student `Toto` is `0` instead of `21`.

I don't understand where the problem?

```js
var students = [
  ['Toto', 4, 17],
  ['Titi', 11, 12],
  ['Tata', 12, 14]
];

var result = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  if (typeof(students[i]) === "number") {
    result += students[i];
  }
  console.log("Student " + students[i][0] + " has the result " + result);
}
```

Comment: `typeof(students[i]) === "number"` will never be the case, because `students[i]` is always an _array_. You have a two-dimensional array here, but so far your code is only looping over the first level, any looping on the second level you have not even gotten to yet.

Comment: I know using modern syntax to achieve the goal might look overwhelming for a beginner. But as soon as you have grabbed the ideas behind it, the code becomes so much more readable, and so much shorter. I haven't used index-based loops in years, and I'm a professional Javascript developer working with this every day. I can only recommend you read into those modern concepts (for..of-loop, const and let, destructuring, and the "new" Array methods introduced with ES6).

Comment: As of now, you picked an answer that shows your code's problems, but outputs wrong results for all except the first data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run this

```js
var students = [
  ['Toto', 4, 17],
  ['Titi', 11, 12],
  ['Tata', 12, 14]
];



for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  var result = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j <= students[i].length; j++) {
    if (typeof(students[i][j]) === "number") {
      result += students[i][j];
    }
  }

  console.log("Student " + students[i][0] + " has the result " + result);
}
```

Comment: between the first and second for lines, you need to reset result to 0. So move the `var result = 0;` line to between the first and second line containing the `for` keyword.

Comment: Please edit your answer so it no longer outputs wrong results for all datasets beyond the first.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use destructuring alongside `Array.prototype.reduce` here:

```js
const students = [['Toto', 4, 17], ['Titi', 11, 12], ['Tata', 12, 14]];

for (const student of students) {
  const [ name, ...summands ] = student;
  console.log(`${name} scored ${summands.reduce((acc,val)=>acc+val,0)}`)
}
```

For an even more concise version, you can destructure right in the for-definition:

```js
const students = [['Toto', 4, 17], ['Titi', 11, 12], ['Tata', 12, 14]];

for (const [ name, ...summands ] of students) {
  console.log(`${name} scored ${summands.reduce((acc,val)=>acc+val,0)}`)
}
```

This will also work for lists of summands varying in length:

```js
const students = [['Toto'], ['Titi', 1,2,3,4,5,6], ['Tata', 12, 14]];

for (const [ name, ...summands ] of students) {
  console.log(`${name} scored ${summands.reduce((acc,val)=>acc+val,0)}`)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `students` array, every item is an array.

```js
const students = [
  ['Toto', 4, 17],
  ['Titi', 11, 12],
  ['Tata', 12, 14]
];


for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  const student = students[i];
  let result = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < student.length; j++) {
    if (typeof(student[j]) === "number") {
      result += student[j];
  }
  
  }
  console.log("Student " + students[i][0] + " has the result " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop iterates over the students, not their grades: you need two loops.

Furthermore, your logging knows that each student is represented by an array whose first element is a string of the student name, so when you add the loop to iterate over the student grades, skip the first entry:

```
for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  var result = 0;
  for (var j = 1; j < students[i].length; j++) {
    result += students[i][j];
  }
  console.log("Student " + students[i][0] + " has the result " + result);
  }
}
```

Note I've also moved your `result` to count per student, you were counting for all students.

There are other ways to do this, but that might not be relevant atm.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var students = [
            ['Toto', 4, 17],
            ['Titi', 11, 12],
            ['Tata', 12, 14]
        ];

        let result = 0;
        students.forEach(item => {
            item.forEach(realItem => {
                if (typeof realItem === 'number'){
                    result += realItem
                }
            })
        })
        console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with for loop

```js
var students = [
  ['Toto', 4, 17],
  ['Titi', 11, 12],
  ['Tata', 12, 14]
];

var result = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  console.log("Student " + students[i][0] + " has the result " + (students[i][1] + students[i][2]));
}
```

or this with `for..of` and `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```js
var students = [
    ['Toto', 4, 17],
    ['Titi', 11, 12],
    ['Tata', 12, 14]
];

for(let [name, ...values] of students) {
 const sum = values.reduce((acc, curr) => acc += curr, 0);
 console.log("Student " + name + " has the result " + sum);
}
```